# Dynamic Authorization by Feature

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have a base controller that receives the Feature Name in the constructor, like below:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
   protected string Feature { get; private set;}

   protected BaseController(){ }
   protected BaseController(string feature)
   {
      this.Feature = feature;
   }
}
```

And in all my controller´s, I construct like this:

```
[AuthorizeUser]
public class ProductController : BaseController
{
   public ProductController(IProductService service)
      : base("Product Management")
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

In my app, the authorization is by feature (not by Action), so, I created an AuthorizeUser attribute and decorate all my controllers.

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

**Is there any way to get the value defined in my base (in the example, "Product Management") in AuthorizeCore**?

I know that method **must be thread-safe**, so, I need some help on how to achieve that. Maybe using other overrides like **OnAuthorization** and **OnCacheAuthorization**? My concern is with the thread-safety

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure it is possible to do what you want. If it is possible I would recomend that you create a new construcor to your AuthorizeUserAttribute and send in the feature.

```
[AuthorizeUser("MySuperFeature")]
```

And then use that feature to validate in AuthorizeCore.

Comment: My concern is with the thread safety. if I declare an instance in my attribute, I risk another thread access this property incorrectly.